# how to create a UV mapping (?) of a texture onto a product photograph based on a calibration pattern

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, photo-editing, photoshop-scripting, blender

UPDATE: [Here you can download high quality images of calibration patterns as well as them printed on socks if anyone wants to give this a go](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j4lDve17SQPuI2zHL4c3a3DL_tKmuttB?usp=sharing)

Pardon my lack of vocabulary, this is not my area of expertise and why I'm looking for some guidance on how to create this product preview. I will most likely end up hiring someone

I'd like to create a system that can map/apply new designs onto an image of a sock worn by a model, with the proper transformations and deformations in order to visualize said designs.

The mapping below can be created by printing a matrix "calibration" design  onto the product. How the actual mapping/deformation is then created in photoshop or other software is what I would like to learn to do. Ideally I'd like to turn it into a process that can be run in a free/open source software that can be run headless in a linux server  (especially as a python script) so I can run it as an internal service for a bunch of designers. As an initial proof of concept a repeatable photoshop or other commercial software action/script would be ok, though!

Things I have:

- a calibration (matrix) design with dot patterns
- socks printed with the matrix dot pattern
- pictures of models wearing the socks

Here is an example of the results I'm trying to achieve:

The pattern to be visualized on the socks
[image: pattern to map]

The pattern as it would be printed on the socks. Note that it's not just a simple overlay  with blending, but actual deformation of the image to take into account the 3D shape of the socks being worn.
[image: pattern "printed" on socks worn by model]

The socks are printed on a cylinder, so the mapping should reflect the bending of the socks at a 45 degree angle. 
[image: pattern "printed" on socks]

Attached are a sample of white socks to do the overlay over:

[image: Sample white socks]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Andres. Since you used the tag *Blender*, please be aware of the specific site https://blender.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hey @PaoloGibellini, thanks for the heads up. I think it's probably not a blender specific task, but rather that a solution might be achievable with blender.

Comment: As long as your images do not have common simple shapes such as straight lines or circles very loose warping should be plausible enough. But the light and shadows should be right. Could you accept it? If yes you can do it in 2D.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge there's no way to use UV data in Photoshop and I'm not sure it would help with this example because the deformation is quite strong: it'd be a job for vector displacement filter (which Photoshop also doesn't have). If I had a task like this I'd go 3d and since you have Blender as a tag, here's a little breakdown of how I'd approach this:

1. Since a sock is a simple object and it doesn't require any complex folds, I'd start with a model from [Daz3d](https://www.daz3d.com/) (free) as a base

   [image]
2. in Blender I'd cut the feet and run it through voxel remesher (to get rid of toes and details) and quad remesher (to get a nice topology)

   [image]
3. then a simple UV-unwrap, eyeballing the distortion

   [image]
4. Here's a result. It took less than an hour from start to finish, if I spent more time I guess it'd be possible to get even better results? To me it looks quite ok even now

   [image]
5. Blender supports python as you probably know already and rendering from CLI, so then you could write a script to reload a texture and simply run something like this:

   `blender --background sock.blend --python change_texture.py -- new_texture.png`

   And in render settings of Blender it'd be also possible to set a set of render passes to render %) so you could have shadows, diffuse lighting, etc as separate images.

   [image]

Comment: Wow, that's incredible you've been able to do all of that so quickly! Thanks for going above and beyond in an answer. I have 0 experience with 3d modeling, and our current approach is similar, and I was trying to build a blender pipeline, but was left hanging by the 3d modeler I had hired... but I can take photographs and can get around photoshop, so that's why I was solution to the problem I proposed. We have different sock models that we would add in the future. That's why I was looking for a solution that I could repeat easily myself. But maybe we should chat?

Comment: @Sergey Kritskiy Nice answer, the only problem I see is the deformation of the unwrapping, probably a cylindrical projection will be more useful.

Comment: @Rafael topology could've been better so the deformation could've been less visible. I think cylindrical projection would bring more deformations (because the object is a very deformed cylinder), but I haven't tried that

Comment: @Andres well, my email address is in my profile if you have any further questions

Comment: the sock is actually printed mounted on a cylinder, and the design files are simply rectangles (think of a rectangle wrapped around a cylinder) -  if that helps, although still hoping to find a photography based approach

Comment: I understand but then it deforms a bit on a foot: a cylinder projection on a deformed model will look artificial (but maybe that's the look you want). For a 2d-solution, maybe a combo of puppet warp and a liquify filter would work

Comment: your answer is simple, effective and on-point. I'd do the same thing in modo, which is my **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tool of choice, in almost the exact same way. The advantage you've given here is both the freeware/open source nature of Blender and the example python to swop and re-render based on new pattern context. Nice answer!

Comment: Just looked up puppet warp and liquify filter and that seems closer to the type of solution I'm looking for. Could that be automated with blender or would it require photoshop?

Answer (score 3):

I repeat my old comment: As long as your images do not have common simple shapes such as straight lines or circles very loose warping should be plausible enough. But the light and shadows should be right. Could you accept it? If yes you can do it in 2D.

An example

One of your unused socks is clipped and pasted over an image of a foot as a new layer. A mesh warp is done to deform the unused sock to the right form. I admit it's not geometrically a masterpiece. Here's a screenshot under the warping:

[image]

Here's the result after warping and fixing a couple of not so good places with the eraser:

[image]

It has unfortunately no shading, it's flat. To get some depth I drew a couple of black strokes to a new layer:

[image]

After blurring the strokes and deleted the extras (selected the emptiness in the warped layer) I got this shading:

[image]

Inserting it and a drop shadow I got the final result:

[image]

This is still quite artificial. Much better result can be got by having a photo of a leg with white sock. Blending mode Multiply would give both perfect shading and a good fabric surface texture at the same time.

The warping can be reused for another photo if you use a program which supports it. I used Affinity Photo, which has unfortunately non-reusable warp mesh.

Illustrator's envelope distort with mesh allows changing the photo. Only release the envelope distortion and apply the mesh to another photo which has identical pixel and millimeter dimensions. Reuse the released mesh in Object > Envelope distort > Make with Top Object.

In Photoshop you can try Puppet Warp to a layer which is converted to smart object. Then it's possible to change the content, because Puppet Warp is a smart filter.

Comment: Yes! I think this is a lot closer to what I'm looking for. Can get you a picture of a leg wearing a white sock.

Comment: Insert a download link so it can be tried. I guess I can have time in 2 days.

Comment: inserted an example white sock picture that you can download. working on getting the grey dot matrix pictures.

Comment: @Andres the white sock photos are very bad. There's enough non-blurred detail only at the top edge and in a couple of other places. Their edges are heavily feathered which alone makes them useless. In addition they have too flat light which totally hides the geometric forms of the legs. Sorry, but you need sharp photos which have geometry revealing lights and shadows. You will not find them from textile seller's web pages, they must be taken with proper equipment for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry about that. We just took some professional photos. Should have them in the next 24 hours. Wanted to see if those would do the trick, but clearly not.

Comment: @user2877001 updated photos added

Comment: @Andres The new photos cannot be used as a fabric texture for the warped artwork. They are full of dark dots which destroy the image. Your original white socks  needed only full area sharpness + natural light & shadow without overexposure. Hopefully you have a cloud of photos of  the absolutely same feet unmoved so that you can make a 3D model with photogrammetry.

Comment: thanks @user287001 - I think the photos should be fine, these were created using those photos with the black dots - those are for creating the mapping